# Back to a 2013 project, I have a lot of "type u_int32_t could not be resolved"

Tags: c++, stdint, uint32-t

I compiled my project in 2013 with g++ v. 4.7.3 under Gentoo Linux and Eclipse Indigo with c++11. In this project, I need integer size perfectly defined. So, I used u_int32_t, u_int8_t types.

Today, I have g++ v. 4.9.2 under Debian Jessie, still with Eclipse Indigo. After having cleaned the project, rebuild leads to "type u_int32_t could not be resolved".

My compiler options:

```
-DDEBUG -ULIMITED_CODE -UDON_T_GROUP_LINES -UREADABLE -ULIMIT_CODES -I/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ -O0 -g3 -c -fmessage-length=0  -std=c++11
```

My first attempt was to add `#include <cstdint>` or `#include <stdint.h>` (deprecated) at the right place, but I get the same error. Seems I have to replace `u_int32_t` by `uint32_t` everywhere.

I have searched for: `type "could not be resolved" "u_int32_t" "uint32_t"` but found nothing.

One other option could be to set-up a Docker with the same versions of g++ and libs than in 2013, but I want to move to recent compiler and libs for many reasons.

My conclusion is then to add `#include <cstdint>` and replace `u_int32_t` by `uint32_t` everywhere. But I would like a confirmation What it is the right wayforward please ?

Comment: Yes, replacement is the right solution.

Comment: Either replace or use typedefs, e.g.  `typedef uint32_t u_int32_t;` or `using u_int32_t = uint32_t;`